# Convert Datatable to generic IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, datatable, ado.net

I am trying to convert from `DataTable` to `IEnumerable<T>`. But what I get is `IEnumerable<DataRow>`:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Connection.ToString()))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Load(reader);

        var res = tbl.AsEnumerable().ToList();  // IEnumerable<DataRow>:
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is:

```
protected async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QuerySqlCmdReadRows<T>(string sqlCommand)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Connection.ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
            cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Load(reader);

            return tbl.AsEnumerable().ToList(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get `IEnumerable<T>` like I can do in [Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)?

```
var studentList = ctx.SqlQuery("Select * from Students")
                     .ToList<Student>();
```

Comment: A DataTable is a collection of DataRow objects, so IEnumerable<DataRow> is the only useful cast. Are you looking for ways to Map the Relational data to Objects? That's the ORM's job. If you want concrete objects, use EF or a microORM like Dapper

Comment: With [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) you can write, eg `var results=con.Query<SomeType>("select .....");` and Dapper will convert the result rows into objects based on the property names. It won't load the results into a DataTable either, it will emit the mapped objects while reading from the DbDataReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension method that convert it for you. Given you have properties on the query that matches the properties on your generic `T` type, you could use reflection to perform it! For sample (see the comments on the code):

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToGenericList<T>(this DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite).ToList();

        var result = new List<T>();

        // loop on rows
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            // create an instance of T generic type.
            var item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            // loop on properties and columns that matches properties
            foreach (var prop in properties)
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)                    
                    if (prop.Name == column.ColumnName)
                    {
                        // Get the value from the datatable cell
                        object value = row[column.ColumnName];

                        // Set the value into the object
                        prop.SetValue(item, value);
                        break;
                    }


            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And given you have a model like this:

```
public class Student 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Code { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    // other possible properties
}
```

You can use the extension method like this:

```
protected async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QuerySqlCmdReadRows<T>(string sqlCommand)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Connection.ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;

            DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
               dtResult.Load(reader);

            return dtResult.ToGenericList<T>();
        }
    }
}

// just and sample
var students = QuerySqlCmdReadRows<Students>("select Id, Code, FirstName, LastName from Students");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I've seen the following errors:
1. `Error CS1061 'PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'HasSetter' and no accessible extension method 'HasSetter' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: 2. `T' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
3. `'T' does not contain a definition for 'SetValue' and no accessible extension method 'SetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
Could you show how they can be solved

Comment: Yes, you're right. The right way to get properties that can recieve some value is `CanWrite` property.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of converting `DataTable` to an `IEnumerable<T>`. It copies over any columns that have matching property or field names.

First, a couple of extensions for dealing with `MemberInfo` as a parent of either `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`:

```
public class MemberInfoExt {
    public static bool GetCanWrite(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return true;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.CanWrite;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
    public static void SetValue(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, object value) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                mfi.SetValue(destObject, value);
                break;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                mpi.SetValue(destObject, value);
                break;
            case MethodInfo mi:
                mi.Invoke(destObject, new object[] { value });
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}
```

Using these, you can write a `DataTable` extension method:

```
public class DataTableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToIEnumerable<T>(this DataTable dt) where T : new() {
        var props = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOrFields()
                             .Where(mi => dt.Columns.Contains(mi.Name) && mi.GetCanWrite())
                             .ToList();
        foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable()) {
            var aT = new T();
            foreach (var p in props)
                p.SetValue(aT, row[p.Name]);
            yield return aT;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it to convert a `DataTable` to a particular type.

It is also possible to convert a `DataTable` to an `IEnumerable<anon>` where `anon` is an anonymous object (or simulation) but that is of questionable value since it requires creating an anonymous object at runtime which can only be used via reflection.